# Using LINQ to access IEnumerable list in Model object to perform a Select and Where

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC view. I am passed the Model to the View and trying to access the property
but I am having issue with access the `IEnumerble` collection in the model object.

```
@Model.Detail.Owners
```

Owners can contain multiple records and defined as

```
public IEnumerable<OwnersDto> Owners { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get the Owner full name with the where clause

```
@Model.Detail.Owners.Select(s=> s.)
```

but when I typed s. the intellisense does not display the property like `FullName`  for Owner. Instead I get a list 
of `ExecuteAsync` and `IfNotNull` options.

I would like something like the following to work

```
@Model.Detail.Owners.Select(s => s.FullName).Where(w => w.Type == "Manager")
```

Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Restart VS  and try again.

Comment: What does intellisense say about the type of `s`? By the way, the `Where` should come first, otherwise it applies to strings.

Answer (score 0):

To fix Intellisense bug, try following this tutorial https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md

I hope it helps you.